# How to Program Outlook 2007 Add-In with Multiple Mailboxes

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-2007

I'm trying to figure how to write a simple add-in for Excel 2007, but one that only interacts with one of my mailboxes.  Currently I have two email addresses coming into my outlook, each in a specific 'mailbox'.  I was wondering, how would I specify a NewMail event for a specific mailbox?

Or, perhaps not as clean, but how could I write an if function that specifies which mailbox / email any new item is addressed to...

Hopefully this makes sense.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch new mail event, add this code to addin startup method:

```
this.Application.NewMailEx += 
    new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(Application_NewMailEx);
```

Then add method to handle NewMailEx event:

```
void Application_NewMailEx(string EntryID)
{
    // get MailItem for this new mail
    Outlook.Explorers explorers = this.Application.Explorers;
    Outlook.MailItem newMail =
        (Outlook.MailItem)explorers.Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryID, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

    // check SendUsingAccount to see if it came in mailbox we are interested in
    if (newMail.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName == "your.name@your.domain.com")
    {
        // do whatever You like
    }
}
```

Add using statement also:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```